# Playframework: Method ok(Content) is not applicable for List-type arguments?

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm reading the book "Play for Java" and trying the example codes. Now I got stuck on a problem: By running this sample code

```
import ...

public class Application extends Controller {

  public static Result index() {

    ...
    ...

        List<StockItem> items = StockItem.find()
                .findList();
        return ok(items);

  }

}
```

ECLIPSE returned an error message that "**The method ok(Content) in the type Results is not applicable for the arguments (List)**".

Does someone know how I can solve it? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what kind of data format you want to return (JSON, XML, etc).
Example shows JSON result:

```
import ...

public class Application extends Controller {

  public static Result index() {
    List<StockItem> items = StockItem.find().findList();
    return ok(Json.toJson(items));
  }

}
```

All variants of "ok" method you can view from source code of Results class: https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/java/play/mvc/Results.java

or javadoc: http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0.2/java/play/mvc/Results.html

Answer (score 3):

`ok()` accepts `String`, `JSON` (as armed wrote), `File` or even `InputStream` but **not** `List` ([check in the code](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/java/play/mvc/Results.java))

Most probably you want to return rendered `view` instead:

```
import views.html.yourview;

public class Application extends Controller {

  public static Result index() {
    List<StockItem> items = StockItem.find().findList();
    return ok(yourview.render(items));
  }

}
```

`/app/views/yourview.scala.html`

```
@(items: List[StockItem])

<ul>
  @for(item <- items){
    <li>@item.title</li>
  }
</ul>
```